# How to display a list of filtered Django model objects with a related field in a template, sorted by date?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django app with a model called 'Book' which has a foreign key relationship with a 'Author' model. The 'Author' model has a 'name' field. I want to display a list of all 'Book' objects along with their corresponding 'Author' names in a template. However, I want to limit the query to only return books that were published after a certain date, and I also want to order the list by the book's publication date in descending order.

Here is the code I have so far:

Models.py

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Book

def book_list(request):
    books = Book.objects.filter(publication_date__gte='2022-01-01').order_by('-publication_date')
    return render(request, 'book_list.html', {'books': books})
```

How can I modify this code to also include the 'Author' name for each 'Book' object in the template?

Answer (score 0):

template

```
{% for i  in books %}
<p> {{ 'publication_date' }} : {{ i.publication_date }} {{ 'author' }} : {{ i.author }} {{ 'title' }} : {{ i.title }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

The `author` field from the `secondary model`(Book) is linked to the `primary model`(Author). When you get it, you will get the author object.

I output part of the model fields in the template through a loop (what is in quotes is just the
string `{{ 'publication_date' }}`.
Here, in each line, the field is accessed, for example, like this: `{{ i.publication_date }}`.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And also I made the Author model return a string name.

`Or` you can refer to the `author field` of the `secondary model` in the template and get the name field of the `primary model` through it

```
{{  i.author.name }}
```